# How do click on btn to display div - then for it to fade out

Tags: jquery, html, popup, fadeout

I am working on a jquery button.

Once clicked on the "heart btn" it needs to pop the total number up on screen then fade out slowly.

This needs to be done for both "cheeky kiss btn " and "ditch btn"

I have  created the hover states but unsure how to create fade out effect when pop up effect when clicked

Once the number has popped up it needs to fade out after 5 seconds

any help would be great, here is my fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/2hVVU/3/

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="profile-pic">
        <ul>
            <div id="love-btns">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#" class="cheeky-kiss-btn"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="ditch-btn"></a></li>
                </ul>
                <div id="cheeky-kiss-btn-hover">Cheeky Kiss :)<span></span></div>
                <div id="ditch-btn-hover">Ditch :(<span></span></div>
                <div class="number-total cheeky kiss">+ 70,101</div>
                <div class="number-total ditch">+ 30,101</div>
            </div>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Once the number has popped up it needs to fade out after 5 seconds

Comment: you can use delay and fadeOut [http://jsfiddle.net/2hVVU/5/](http://jsfiddle.net/2hVVU/5/)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. How would I fix the small bug. Once you click on "cheeky kiss" and then quickly click on "ditch " numbers overlap.? could you hide the first click before the second is shown?

Comment: [http://jsfiddle.net/2hVVU/7/](http://jsfiddle.net/2hVVU/7/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although not certain - I believe this is what you are looking for. Your numbers will originally be hidden and then the number associated with the clicked button will show (pop up) and fade over 5 seconds:

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/2hVVU/6/)

```
$(".number-total").hide();

/*  CHEEKY KISS POP UP
===================================================================*/

$("a.cheeky-kiss-btn").hover(function(){
    $("#cheeky-kiss-btn-hover").show();
}, function(){
    $("#cheeky-kiss-btn-hover").hide();
}).click(function() {
    $(".cheeky").show().fadeOut(5000);
});

/*  DITCH POP UP
===================================================================*/

$("a.ditch-btn").hover(function(){
    $("#ditch-btn-hover").show();
}, function(){
    $("#ditch-btn-hover").hide();
}).click(function() {
    $(".ditch").show().fadeOut(5000);
});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. How would I fix the small bug. Once you click on "cheeky kiss" and then quickly click on "ditch " numbers overlap.? could you hide the first click before the second is shown?

Comment: @PaulDesigner , within the click you could hide the other number.. for example in the `a.cheeky-kiss-btn` click function you could add `$(".ditch").hide()` before showing `.cheeky`.

Comment: @PaulDesigner, I was noticing some odd things if you clicked back and forth during the fading... i added stops and this seems to work fine.. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2hVVU/9/)

Comment: could you make a fiddle please? i cant get it to work

Comment: @PaulDesigner, also just fyi, "cheeky kiss" in the class will actually make your element have 2 extra classes, "cheeky" and "kiss". I'm not sure if you realize this or not so I thought I'd point it out.

Answer (score 1):

Just add

```
$("#cheeky-kiss-btn-hover").fadeOut(5000);
```

and

```
$("#ditch-btn-hover").fadeOut(5000);
```

respectively after the show() functions.

Answer (score 1):

Additional CSS:

```
.number-total {
    display: none;
}
```

Additional JS:

```
$("a.cheeky-kiss-btn").on("click", function () {
    $(".number-total.cheeky.kiss").show();
    setTimeout(function() {
        $(".number-total.cheeky.kiss").fadeOut('slow');
    }, 5000);
});

$("a.ditch-btn").on("click", function () {
    $(".number-total.ditch").show();
    setTimeout(function() {
        $(".number-total.ditch").fadeOut('slow');
    }, 5000);
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hm6gF/

Note that this will only *start* fading out *after* 5 seconds. If you want it to start fading out immediately and fade out *over* 5 seconds, remove the setTimeout and change `'slow'` to `5000` instead.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. How would I fix the small bug. Once you click on "cheeky kiss" and then quickly click on "ditch " numbers overlap.? could you hide the first click before the second is shown?

Answer (score 1):

**this might be easier**

```
$('.trig').each(function(i){
    $(this).hover(function() {//hover
        $('.hov').eq(i).show();
    }, function(){
        $('.hov').eq(i).hide();
    }).click(function() {//click
        $('.number-total:visible').stop().fadeOut();//stop queue buildup
        $('.number-total').eq(i).stop(false,true).fadeIn().delay(5000).fadeOut();
    });
});
```

I added a few css classes to make the javascript and css work better together. `trig` on the buttons & `hov` on the pop-ups.

made a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/filever10/42vtX/

**edit** added a clause to stop/reverse animation to prevent queue buildup.